# Bug found in XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-formula

Try this code:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField4">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var td= @Adjust(@Date(2015,3,1), 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return @Text(@Year(td))+","+@Text(@Month(td))+","+@Text(@Day(td));
    }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

Expected output: 2015,4,1

Actual output: 2015,3,29

UPDATE

This solves the problem, but is there a shorter version:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField4">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var cal= java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        var td:Date= cal.getTime();
        return td.getFullYear()+","+(td.getMonth()+1)+","+td.getDate();
    }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

TIA.

Comment: I recommend don't focus on a shorter solution.  That works well.  The best thing about it is you're not using the @formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce on 9.0.1 FP2 HF1 on Windows and `@Date(2015,3,1)` in a Computed Field in UK locale returns 1st March, as expected. But this may be a factor http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=5655E1203988BEF0852578CB0066A339. You will be going across daylight savings time, as well as combining local and UTC.
The update is the better method. Your using only Java objects then, so no reliance on manipulations internally. Plus you're dealing with the `Calendar` object that has both date and time and is locale-specific, rather than setting `@Date()` without a time, then running `@Adjust`, which does and also going across the start of DST.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and found that I get 2015, 4, 1.  Which version of Domino are you running?  I tried it on 9.0.1FP2 HF384 on Win 64.

Comment: I can reproduce Buggers problem and get 2015,3,29. I am using 9.0.1 FP3 Win64. Could it be a regional problem? I am using region sweden

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that: Domino 9.0.1 FP2 on Windows/7/64 6.1

Comment: I have mine set to UK.  Strange.  Reading it again, it seems as though internally, the system thinks that the date is 29th February and then adding a month produces 29th March.  I would be interested to see what the `@Date(2015,3,1)` returns before it is adjusted.  This way we can see whether it is a `Date` or `@Date()` issue rather than an `@Adjust()` problem.

Comment: My guess: it's got the month wrong. It somehow thinks it needs the number of days for February, adds 28, and returns the 29th.

Comment: I believe this is a regional settings problem, you need to specify timezone, I think you will get the correct date if you add 1 month and 1 hour.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115961/dates-are-adjusted-for-users-only-at-midnight-on-my-xpages

Comment: So you think it takes March 1st 00:00 midnight over here (TZ+1), which is February 28th 23:00 GMT, adds one month to arrive at March 28th 23:00 which is March 29th 00:00 here... very plausible indeed! But is it correct behaviour? By the way, I did this yesterday, using @Today, and got the wrong answer.